# Can i use putblock as append blob?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-blob-storage

So I am trying to upload file chunk by chunk...
[Can PutBlock be used to append to an existing BlockBlob in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368954/can-putblock-be-used-to-append-to-an-existing-blockblob-in-azure) from this example...
I am uploading a 20mb file but finally, when I see it on the container it is 7mb and when I download blob it is broken... What am I doing wrong?

```
 public async Task AppendBlobOnAsset(Stream stream, MediaServiceRequest request)
        {
            var cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(request.InputAssetStorageUri);
            var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(request.BlobName);

            var blockList = new List<ListBlockItem>();
            var blockListItems = new List<string>();
            if (true)
            {
                var blocks = await blockBlob.DownloadBlockListAsync();
                blockList = blocks.ToList();
                blockListItems = blockList.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            }
            //string blockId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("m");
            string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0000005"));
            blockBlob.PutBlock(blockId, stream, null);

            blockListItems.Add(blockId);
            blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockListItems);
        }


  using var file = File.OpenRead("C:\\Projects\\file.mp4");
            int bytesRead;
            var appendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes = 4000000;
            var buffer = new byte[appendBlobMaxAppendBlockBytes];
            while ((bytesRead = await file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                var newArray = new Span<byte>(buffer, 0, bytesRead).ToArray();
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(newArray);
                stream.Position = 0;
                await AppendBlobOnAsset(stream, request);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async Task AppendBlobOnAssetAsync(int blockId, Stream stream, MediaServiceRequest request)
        {
            var cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(request.InputAssetStorageUri);
            var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(request.BlobName);

            var blockItems = new List<ListBlockItem>();
            var blockItemIds = new List<string>();

            if (blockId > 0)
            {
                var blocks = await blockBlob.DownloadBlockListAsync();
                blockItems = blocks.ToList();
                blockItemIds = blockItems.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            }

            var Id = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadLeft(30, '0')));

            blockBlob.PutBlock(Id, stream, null);

            blockItemIds.Add(Id);
            blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockItemIds);
        }
```